# Vanishing viscosity in eqn. of heat transfer for free convection: on what argument?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

In Landau's and Lifshitz' **Fluid Mechanics** on the derivation of the equation of heat transfer for free convection p. 218, they write

> In the thermal conduction equation (50.2), the viscosity term can be shown to
>   be small in free convection compared with the other terms, and may therefore be
>   omitted.

Namely, in the following equation (p. 197):
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{grad}\, T = \chi \bigtriangleup\! T + \frac{\nu}{2 c_p} \left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k} + \frac{\partial v_k}{\partial x_i} \right)^2
$$

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but on what grounds exactly does that term vanish? How exactly can I show that it should be much smaller than the other terms in the equation?

Comment: It's not zero, it's just negligible. This only holds for natural convention at a low Prandl number, and can be deduced by dimensional analysis, see e.g. https://www.thermalfluidscentral.org/encyclopedia/index.php/Scale_analysis_of_natural_convection